# Why is the Adjoint Representation of a Simple Algebraic Group visible?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected simple complex algebraic group.  Then $G$ acts on its lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ by the adjoint representation.  Write $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]$ for the coordinate ring of the affine algebraic variety $\mathfrak{g}$. The algebra of invariants $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G\subseteq \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]$ induces a map of spaces $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G\cong\mathbb{A}^{\text{rk}(G)}$, where I am using that the Duflo isomorphism says that $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G\cong \mathcal{Z}(\mathfrak{g})$, where $\mathcal{Z}(\mathfrak{g})$ is the center of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ (note- I'm not sure if this last comment is actually relevant to answering the question).

I have read this representation is $\it{visible}$, meaning that the fibers of $\pi$ have finitely many $G$-orbits (equivalently $\pi^{-1}(\pi(0))$ has finitely many $G$-orbits).  I can't see the reason, does anyone have an explanation for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explicit the map pi? And what is A?

Comment: Sorry, $\pi$ is the map on spaces induced from the inclusion of algebra $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]^G\subseteq\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]$

Comment: I just realized that I don't know that it is not the map induced on schemes because rings are far from being commutative... In other words, I don't know what are you talking about XD sorry!

Comment: All rings are commutative.  By $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}]$ I mean the coordinate ring of the affine algebraic variety $\mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero-fibre is the nilpotent cone, so this follows from the fact that there are only finitely many conjugacy classes of nilpotent elements.

More generally, for $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ let $X=X_s+X_n$ be its Jordan decomposition. Then, $\pi(X)=\pi(X_s)$ and $\pi(X)=\pi(Y)$ if and only if $X_s$ and $Y_s$ are conjugate.

For more on this map see:

- Kostant, Lie group representations on polynomial rings, Amer. J. Math. 85 1963 327–404
- Chriss, Ginzburg, Representation theory and complex geometry. Modern Birkhäuser Classics. Birkhäuser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 2010.